# сборка RoR без database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Имеется скачанный с гитхаба проект на  RoR. Собрал к нему все необходимые гемы, но при rake db:migrate возникает ошибка из-за отсутсвия файла database.yml, но есть все миграции и схема базы данных. Как можно запустить этот сайт на локалке? я новичок в этом деле, пожалуйста помогите.Я даже не представляю с чего начать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При инициализации приложения, rails подгружает все необходимое окружение, в том числе и коннект к БД. При создании коннекта для базы данных, конфигурации для подключения берутся из файла `config/database.yml`. Соответсвенно, чтобы запустить rails приложение, вам необходим этот файл.

Чем заполнять этот файл? Для начала вам необходимо развернуть свой инстанс СУБД. Это может быть **postgresql**, **sqlite**, **mysql** или что-то еще, в зависимости от миграций и требования приложения. С какой именно СУБД будет без ошибок работать приложение, можно узнать либо в документации к приложению, а если в документации это не указано, то посмотреть в файл Gemfile.

Если вы видите в Gemfile строчку [gem "pg"](https://github.com/ged/ruby-pg), то вам необходимо развернуть PostgreSQL, если вы видите [gem "mysql2"](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) или нечто подобное, то MySQL, если [gem "sqlite3"](https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby) или нечто подобное, то sqlite. Документацию по установке и настройке каждой СУБД можно без проблем найти через гугл, в том числе и на русском языке.

После того как вы установите и настроете СУБД, вам необходимо создать файл `config/database.yml` примерно с таким содержимым:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql # или sqlite3, или mysql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: 5
  username: ИМЯ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ_СУБД
  password: ПАРОЛЬ_ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ_СУБД
  host: localhost 
  port: 5432 # или другой, взависимости от ваших настроек

development:
  <<: *default
  # имя вашей базы данных, произвольное. Для sqlite путь к файлу
  database: my_app_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_test
```

После конфигурирования файла, вы можете попробовать запустить миграции:

```
bundle exec rake db:create && bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

- `rake db:create` - создаст необходимые базы данных, имена которых вы указали в конфиге под `database`
- `rake db:migrate` - накатит все миграции в базу

Подробнее о миграциях в rails: http://rusrails.ru/rails-database-migrations

Если что-то пошло не так, то внимательно изучите ваш `config/database.yml`, все ли вы корректно указали. Ну а если все верно, но все равно не работает, то мы ждем вас с новым постом на SO :)

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ!. Сделал конфигурационный файл database.yml, Затем в терминале сделал: bundle exec rake db:migrate.  
Ответ был: created database ‘DB_dev’
Created database ‘DB_test’ и Затем rails db:schema:load , команда выполнилась без ошибок

Comment: @supervitas отлично, всегда пожалуйста :) важно понимать, что `rails db:schema:load` формирует структуру БД на основании файла `db/schema.rb`, а не прогоняет каждую миграцию отдельно, как в случае с `rails db:migrate`

Comment: @supervitas [примите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), если он вам помог